# how do i manage role and permission in server side for my predefined roles and assign permission in wso2 identity server?

Tags: .net, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

currently i am using the wso2 identity server here i have made an traditional application and and with in that application i have authorize certain apis now as i create the role i can pass the permissions to those roles and assign the roles to the users and i also can assign the user and roles for the application now i backend or server side how do i manage roles and permissions.In backend i have made the auth filter for authentication and while communication with wso2 the return access token should contain the permission and roles of assign user so that i can validate the user in backend and also i can validate the ui in frontend based on the  user assigned roles and permission??

i tried rbac and got the roles through attribute which is predefined in scope now i want to get the permission assign to those roles ???